# Ionic command cordova fails in Azure DevOps Build-Pipeline

Tags: android, ios, ionic4, devops, bing-maps

Azure DevOps Build fails build with Ionic Command cordova "build ios --release --buildConfig=build.json --device --verbose".

The problem seems to be the bingmaps-integration.

Use versions are:
- Node 7.10.1
- Ionic 4.12.0
- Cordova 8.1.2

I tried to run the pipeline with different version of Ionic and Cordova.

> ### [section]Starting: Ionic Command cordova
>
> ============================================================================== Task         : Ionic Command Description  : Run an Ionic CLI command
>   Version      : 1.3.12 Author       : Microsoft Corporation Help
>   : [More Information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=692057)
>   ============================================================================== Module cache at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules cordova@8.1.2
>   already installed. Cordova Module Path:
>   /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova
>   Module cache at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules ionic@4.12.0
>   already installed. Ionic Module Path:
>   /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/ionic/4.12.0/node_modules/ionic
>   2019-09-17T07:06:26.009Z ionic:bootstrap local CLI 3.20.0 found at
>   /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/pm-references/node_modules/ionic/package.json
>   2019-09-17T07:06:26.086Z ionic:utils-terminal Environment variables
>   for CI detected: CI 2019-09-17T07:06:26.158Z ionic:lib Terminal info:
>   { tty: false, ci: true, windows: false } 2019-09-17T07:06:26.159Z
>   ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'ios' ],
>   help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: false,
>   color: true, confirm: null, json: null, release: true, buildConfig:
>   'build.json', device: true, project: null, '--': [] } [WARN] Detected
>   locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using global CLI.
>   2019-09-17T07:06:26.354Z ionic:lib:project Project type from config:
>   Ionic 2/3 (ionic-angular) 2019-09-17T07:06:26.355Z ionic:lib:project
>   Project details: { configPath:
>   '/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/pm-references/ionic.config.json',
>   errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'ionic-angular' }
>   2019-09-17T07:06:26.358Z ionic Context: { binPath:
>   '/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/ionic/4.12.0/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic',
>   libPath:
>   '/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/ionic/4.12.0/node_modules/ionic',
>   execPath: '/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/pm-references', version:
>   '4.12.0' } 2019-09-17T07:06:26.480Z
>   ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Using config.xml:
>   /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/pm-references/config.xml
>   2019-09-17T07:06:26.536Z ionic:lib:hooks Looking for
>   ionic:build:before npm script. 2019-09-17T07:06:26.537Z
>   ionic:lib:project:ionic-angular:build Looking for ionic:build npm
>   script.
>
> > ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform ios 2019-09-17T07:06:26.538Z ionic:lib:project:ionic-angular:build Found
> >     ionic:build, but it is the default. Not running. [07:06:28]‌ 
> >     ionic-app-scripts 1.3.7 ‌ [07:06:28]‌  build dev started ‌...‌ ‌
> >     [07:06:28]‌  clean started ‌...‌ ‌ [07:06:28]‌  clean finished ‌in 1
> >     ms‌ ‌ [07:06:28]‌  copy started ‌...‌ ‌ [07:06:28]‌  transpile started
> >     ‌...‌ ‌ [07:06:37]  typescript:
> >     node_modules/@types/bingmaps/Autosuggest.d.ts, line: 78
> >     ‌
> >                 Duplicate identifier 'AutosuggestManager'.
>
> ```
>   L78:  ‌export class ‌A‌u‌t‌o‌s‌u‌g‌g‌e‌s‌t‌M‌a‌n‌a‌g‌e‌r‌ {‌ [07:06:37]  typescript:
> ```
>
> node_modules/@types/bingmaps/Clustering.d.ts, line: 56
>   ‌
>
> [07:06:37]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/bingmaps/Clustering.d.ts, line: 56
>   ‌
>               Duplicate identifier 'MeanAverage'.  [07:06:37]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/bingmaps/Clustering.d.ts, line: 62
>   ‌
>
> ```
>   L56:  ‌        ‌M‌e‌a‌n‌A‌v‌e‌r‌a‌g‌e‌,‌
> ```
>
> [07:06:37]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/bingmaps/Clustering.d.ts, line: 69
>   ‌
>               In an enum with multiple declarations, only one declaration can omit an initializer for its first enum 
>               element.  [07:06:37]  typescript: node_modules/@types/bingmaps/Clustering.d.ts, line: 86
>   ‌
>
> [07:06:37]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/bingmaps/Contour.d.ts, line: 23 ‌
>         L56:  ‌        ‌M‌e‌a‌n‌A‌v‌e‌r‌a‌g‌e‌,‌
>
> ```
>         Duplicate identifier 'FirstLocation'. 
>
>   L62:  ‌    ‌F‌i‌r‌s‌t‌L‌o‌c‌a‌t‌i‌o‌n‌
>
>         Duplicate identifier 'ClusterPushpin'. 
>
>   L69:  ‌export class ‌C‌l‌u‌s‌t‌e‌r‌P‌u‌s‌h‌p‌i‌n‌ extends Pushpin {‌
>   L70:  ‌    &#x2F;** An array of all the pushpins that are in the cluster. *&#x2F;‌
>
>         Duplicate identifier 'ClusterLayer'. 
>
>   L86:  ‌export class ‌C‌l‌u‌s‌t‌e‌r‌L‌a‌y‌e‌r‌ implements IDataLayer {‌
>
>         Duplicate identifier 'ContourLine'. 
>
>   L23:  ‌export class ‌C‌o‌n‌t‌o‌u‌r‌L‌i‌n‌e‌ extends Polygon {‌
>   L24:  ‌    &#x2F;** The contour lines that are directly nested inside this contour line *&#x2F;‌
>
>         Duplicate identifier 'ContourLayer'. 
>
>   L44:  ‌export class ‌C‌o‌n‌t‌o‌u‌r‌L‌a‌y‌e‌r‌ extends Layer {‌
>
>         Duplicate identifier 'circle'.  (Location | IPrimitive)[], distance: number, units‌
>
>         Duplicate identifier 'Square'. 
>
>  L327:  ‌ * C‌a‌l‌c‌u‌l‌a‌tes the center of a shape.‌
>  L328:  ‌ * @param shape The shape to calculate the center of.‌
>
>         Duplicate`enter code here` identifier 'TrafficManager'. 
>
>   L54:  ‌        &#x2F;** Displays the traffic flow layer. *&#x2F;‌
>   L55:  ‌        public sh‌o‌w‌F‌l‌o‌w‌(‌)‌:‌ ‌v‌o‌i‌d‌;‌
> ```
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
>
> ```
>     ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform ios exited with exit code 1.
>
>     Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information. 2019-09-17T07:06:37.544Z ionic:utils-process
> ```
>
> onBeforeExit handler: process.exit received 2019-09-17T07:06:37.544Z
>   ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions
>   2019-09-17T07:06:37.580Z ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler:
>   exiting (exit code 1)
>
> ### [error]Task failed
>
> ### [section]Finishing: Ionic Command cordova

Comment: This problem is solved in the meantime.
I removed the @types/bingmaps from the package.json. It is no longer needed.

Comment: I am also trying to build and release my Ionic 4 app, but can't find any up to date examples on how to do this. Could you please explain or create a screenshot of your build and release pipeline?